# Scala map function over RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have following structure in my RDD

`((String, String) (Int, Int))` and I want to map that to `(String, String, Int, Int)`

```
rdd.map((a, b) => "%s|%s|%s|%s".format(a._1, a._2, b._1, b._2))
```

I get the following error:
 error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1

I also tried, but got compilation error.

```
rdd.map((a), (b)) => "%s|%s|%s|%s".format(a._1, a._2, b._1, b._2))

rdd.map((tuple1._1, tuple1._2), (tuple2._1, tuple2._2)) => "%s|%s|%s|%s".format(tuple1._1, tuple1._2, tuple2._1, tuple2._2))
```

Would be great to get some help on this.

Comment: because the `map` method of RDD need a function with one parameter. So in your case, it should be `rdd.map(e => "%s|%s|%s|%s".format(e._1._1, e._1._2, e._2._1, e._2._2))`

Comment: What language are you coming from to possibly think that formatting a string will end up in a tuple?!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you're trying to make a string, but I think this is what you want
`rdd.map{case ((a,b),(c,d)) => (a,b,c,d))}`. Scala extractor objects rule!!