# Maniputale CSV with scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a csv file which is "semi-structured"

```
canal,username,email,age
facebook,pepe22,anyemail@gmail.com,24
twitter,foo-24,anyemail@gmail.com,33
facebook,caty24,,22
```

suppose that i want the first column the second and the third column into an RDD org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String)]

I am realy new, im using spark 1.4.1 ,my code reach here

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/user/ergorenova/socialmedia/allus/test").map(_.split(","))
```

Can someone help me?

I would really appreciate it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala map function over RDD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565351/scala-map-function-over-rdd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/user/ergorenova/socialmedia/allus/test")
            .map( _.split(",",-1) match {

               case Array(canal, username, email) => (canal, username, email)

               case Array(canal, username, email, age) => (canal, username, email)
            })
```

You will obtain a tuple made out of the first,second and third column.

Comment: Thank you very much, but now, i have other issue, if i don´t have the last element, for example without age, the code fail, how i can solve this?

Comment: error in the second line "not found: value age" , another way? thanks for response

Comment: if edit this line "case Array(canal, username, email) => (canal, username, age)" with "case Array(canal, username, email) => (canal, username, "")" works, this solution is right??

Comment: Sorry, the last part should be email and not age. I mixed them.

Comment: not problem, the issue is that now i want age, and i don´t have this data in one record on this file, and i have an error.

Comment: The problem is that you have empty strings in the csv which will not be returned by the [ split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689065/how-to-split-string-with-trailing-empty-strings-in-result).

Comment: Modified to `_.split(",",-1)` to handle this case